# c replace dot with comma in a float number

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm developing a simple GTK+3 program that do simple calculation.
I have a problem with floating point number because if i write `.` instead of `,` the total will be wrong.
So I have `float price;` and i want to replace `.` with `,`.

Example: user write `100.60` as price and i want to convert it into `100,60`. How can i do it?
I've thought to `strchr` but it is a float and i think i cannot use it xD
Thanks :)

EDIT: added the code

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *grid;
GtkWidget *c_button;
GtkWidget *q_button;
GtkWidget *u_name;
GtkWidget *h_name;
GtkWidget *pass;
GtkWidget *label_user;
GtkWidget *label_host;
GtkWidget *label_pass;

/* Funzione attivata alla pressione del pulsante connect */
int calcolo_guadagno(void){
    int num_btp, i, len;
    float prezzo_attuale, subtotale, totale, diff_prezzo_attuale, PREZZO_PARTENZA = 99.42;
    char cmcd[15];
    num_btp = (atoi(gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(h_name)))/PREZZO_PARTENZA);
    prezzo_attuale = atof(gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(u_name)));
    diff_prezzo_attuale = (prezzo_attuale - PREZZO_PARTENZA);
    subtotale = (num_btp * diff_prezzo_attuale);
    totale = subtotale-((subtotale/100)*12.5);
    if(prezzo_attuale < PREZZO_PARTENZA){
        strcpy(cmcd, "Sei in perdita...");
        gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(pass),cmcd);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    if(prezzo_attuale == PREZZO_PARTENZA){
        strcpy(cmcd, "Sei in pari...");
        gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(pass),cmcd);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    sprintf(cmcd, "%.3f", totale);
    gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(pass),cmcd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}



   int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    /* Inizializziamo le librerie GTK+ */
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    /* Creiamo la finestra principale, impostiamo il titolo, la posizione e la dimensione */
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Calcolo Guadagno BTP");
    gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW(window), 350, 250);

    /* Quando premiamo chiudi si 'disturgge' tutto */
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    /* Impostiamo il bordo e dichiariamo le finestra ridimensionabile */
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), TRUE);

    /* Creiamo una nuova griglia, la aggiungiamo alla finestra e impostiamo gli spazi fra i vari widget */
    grid = gtk_grid_new ();
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), grid);
    gtk_grid_set_row_spacing (GTK_GRID (grid), 3);

    /* Creiamo delle label con il relativo nome */
    label_user = gtk_label_new("Prezzo attuale ");
    label_host = gtk_label_new("Soldi investiti ");
    label_pass = gtk_label_new("Guadagno netto ");

    /* Creo una entry_text */
    h_name = gtk_entry_new();
    /* Impostiamo il testo trasparente che scompare quando clicco o scrivo */
    gtk_entry_set_placeholder_text (GTK_ENTRY (h_name), "Soldi investiti");
    u_name = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_entry_set_placeholder_text (GTK_ENTRY (u_name), "Prezzo attuale");
    pass = gtk_entry_new();
    /* Impostiamo il campo password non visibile */
    gtk_editable_set_editable (GTK_EDITABLE (pass), 0);
    /* Creiamo i pulsanti e li connettiamo alle relative funzioni */
    c_button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Calcola");
    g_signal_connect (c_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (calcolo_guadagno), NULL);
    q_button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Esci");
    g_signal_connect (q_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    /* Imposto i widget come espandibili sia in orizzontale che in verticale */
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand(u_name, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand(u_name, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand(h_name, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand(h_name, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand(pass, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand(pass, TRUE);

    /* Posizioniamo i widget all'interno della griglia */
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), label_host, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), h_name, 1, 0, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), label_user, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), u_name, 1, 1, 2, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), label_pass, 0, 2, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), pass, 1, 2, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), c_button, 0, 3, 2, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), q_button, 0, 4, 2, 1);

    /* Mostriamo tutti i widget */
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    /* Entriamo nel loop principale delle GTK+, da questo punto  l'applicazione attende l'accadere di un qualsiasi evento */
    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that there is no comma in the internal representation of a float. The comma is just an effect of printing a `float` value to the screen depending on the locale. That means your conversion has nothing to do with the float, but how you represent it. Also, representing prices as floats is usually a really really bad idea.

Comment: i know but it is only a personal program :D nothing that will be shared!

Comment: @poslinux If you are not proud enough of your code to show it to others, it is not worth of being written. :)

Comment: Okay, it's good that you've added some code, but there's a lot of code that you can probably cut out, as it's not relevant to the example. Can you provide a [Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: less thant this it is not possbible :D

Comment: @polslinux Sure it is. You could get rid of all the GTK stuff, and just use `gets()` to get a single string from the command line that has the `'.'` that you want to be a `','`.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [setlocale](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/clocale/setlocale/).

If you are using a locale that uses comma as seperator, it will be used in input/output operations.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yes and no! This not solve my completely my problem...i need and explicit `.` to `,` conversion!

Answer (score 3):

The [strpbrk](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strpbrk/) function in `<string.h>` can help.

```
void dot_to_comma(char *input) {
    char *ptr = NULL;
    while(ptr = strpbrk(input, ".")) { //find the first dot in input
        *ptr = ','; //replace the dot with a comma
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong? Can you give more information as to how it doesn't work?

Comment: simply it doesn't find the "." :)

Comment: @polslinux How are you determining that the `'.'` isn't found? Do you have some code that notifies you inside the while loop?

Comment: @polslinux Interesting... Try printing out `input` before the while loop to make sure that the string you're giving it has a `'.'` in it.

Answer (score 3):

Having prices as floats is in general a very bad idea. floating-point arithmetic is imprecise and will come back to bite you in very weird situations. Use a `struct` to represent both parts of the currency and then implement some arithmetic and printing with them.

```
type struct {
  int main;
  int sub;
} money;

void add(money* result, money* x, money* y);

void print(money* x);
void read(money* result, const char* input);
```

Your print function can explicitly specify what separator should be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i;
int len = strlen(string);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (string[i] == '.') {
        string[i] = ',';
        i = len; // or `break;`
    }
}
```

Comment: but i have a float not a string!

Comment: char buffer [50];  sprintf(buffer, %f, price);

Comment: @polslinux Where does the value of the float come from, then? You say "user write `100.60`...", so that implies that there is user input, which would be a string.

Comment: Is a `atof(gtk_entry_get_text...)` PS: your code doesn't works :(